# Send email through AWS SES SMTP 554 Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We are using java to connect the AWS SES SMTP to send the email message. The normal message could sent successfully. But some are failed with response Access denied: User ARN is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource ARN. We use the verified email address as from address, if the address set the identity policy it won't fail. Is anyone know what kind of email will be sent as RAW email by AWS and why it required identity policy?
I didn't find any document to state require the policy

The SES in the sandbox
The from email already verified. The IAM user already set up the policy as

```
  "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ses:SendEmail",
            "ses:SendRawEmail"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
```

If the from email set up the identify policy it will set raw email succeed.

Comment: are SES user and SES domain verified in different account or same account ?

Comment: In same account and not domain verified，just email verified in sandbox.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-response-codes.html based on this, you might be using some incorrect credentials , can you try to create a new credential from SES console --> SMTP settings and try it again?

Comment: The problem casue by the to address doesn't verified. But in the log it print out the from email address, that's weird

Comment: I don't think so that was the problem but glad to hear it worked for you.